# How to debug csh scripts?

Tags: shell-script, debugging, csh

My lab uses csh scripts to run jobs. It is usually difficult for me to debug a shell script, so I'm wondering if there is a csh debugger I can use.

I know there are some flags like `-x` or `-v` that can help, but because the script is kind of long, it would be better if I can set breakpoints on it. As I searched online, I found there is a debugger specifically for bash scripts that supports breakpoints, but I couldn't find one for csh scripts. Will the bash debugger work? Is there a csh-specific debugger I can use?

Comment: Doesn't `csh -x yourScript.sh` cut it?

Comment: I dont think "shell" has debugger, just `echo` the values out or use `-x`

Answer (score 6):

[This page](http://www.starlink.rl.ac.uk/docs/sc4.htx/node79.html) lists two useful `csh` switches: `-v` to show each command before variables are substituted, and `-x` to show them afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `-v` and `-x`, you can stop execution for an arbitrary amount of time in `csh` by assigning `$<` to a variable that you aren't using

`set unused_var = $<`

This will block until you've read a line from `/dev/tty`, so it works even if your script is in a pipeline.

This gives you the ability to run commands and "look around" before the script is done executing.